# Flink application is not stopping and going to ready state

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-flink

I am running flink application on AWS. The application is triggered when there is a file uploaded to s3. It becomes RUNNING from READY when there is a file uploaded to s3. It runs and then becomes READY again. But if there is an exception, the application is still running and does to go to ready state.
This is my code
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException {

```
    Pipeline pipeline = null;
    try {
        Map<String, Properties> applicationProperties = KinesisAnalyticsRuntime.getApplicationProperties();
        Properties pipelineProperties = applicationProperties.get("BeamApplicationProperties");
        String[] pipelineFromRunTimeEnv = getRunTimeConfig(pipelineProperties);
        BatchPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(ArrayUtils.addAll(pipelineFromRunTimeEnv, args)).as(BatchPipelineOptions.class);
        initializeOptions(options);
        initExecutionEnvironment();
        pipeline = createPipeline(options);
        Instant startTime = Instant.now();
        runBatchProcessing(pipeline,startTime);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        handleFailureAndTransitionToReadyState(e);
    }

}
private static void handleFailureAndTransitionToReadyState(Throwable cause) {
    // Implement logic to handle failure and transition to ready state
    System.out.println("Handling failure and transitioning to ready state...");
    // Log the error
    System.err.println("Error occurred: " + cause.getMessage());
    // Perform any necessary cleanup or state transition operations
    // For example, notify a monitoring system or update application status
    // Here, you can implement custom logic based on your requirements
    System.exit(0);
}
```

even though i exit gracefully, the application is still in running state and not ready state